# SharePoint web part content disappearing

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, content-editor

I have been creating web pages using MS Word 2007 and creating hyperlinks within them. Then I am turning them into Web Page documents. I am then creating a picture library specifically for that page on SharePoint and using DreamWeaver 2004 to link the pictures from the library into the web page source code. 
I then create a content editor web part and using the Source editor use the code from Dreamwever. After extending the pixel height and width to accommodate the file I apply and publish. It's been working like a dream, giving me fantastic pages. But twice now I've gone in to the pages and found the content of the web parts to be blank! On all the pages! I try to see what's going on so I edit the page but when I go to Modify the Web Part specifically, the page jumps and won't let me click "edit". I can, however, click the "x" next to it and delete the web part entirely. When viewing the page and looking at the source code I can see my original code is there, so it's like it's hidden as opposed to it disappearing. The error message that comes up at the bottom left reads "'MSOMenu_WebPartMenu' is undefined". This has completely baffled everyone at my work including the people in ICT. Can anyone shed some light on this for me and help? Nothing I've pulled up on Google seems to be the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed anything about the layout recently? It seems a bit like the issue described here: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/css-causes-javascript-error-while-moving-web-parts-in-edit-mode/ (except for the Web Part getting blank).